# access to basicHTTP binding through WCF - results in Forbidden

Tags: wcf, wcf-binding, wcf-security, wcf-http

I am trying to access a web service using WCF client application in CS, when trying to access the web method. I am getting the forbidden error.

Binding configuration:basicHttpBinding
endpoint address=http://xxxxx/yyyy/WebServices/Soap/Query.svc

I noticed 1 more thing - when I try to add the service reference to WCF through VS - it is https://xxxx/yyyy/Webservices/Soap but in app Config it shows http. 
Does anyone know how to handle this or what I am missing? 
Please do help for the same.

Here is the call stack for the same:

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at ConsoleApplication1.xxxxxx.Query.Result(String userName, String password, String workflowName, String queryId, QueryData data)
   at ConsoleApplication1.UTPQueryService.QueryClient.Result(String userName, String password, String workflowName, String queryId, QueryData data) in

Comment: have you configured baseAddress on server? If yes, which protocol you have used http or https?

Comment: so the base address on the server is configured as Http -> have tried modifying the URL with http but the problem still exists.